# Binding MVC view to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have this in a view:

```
  @{
    var i = 0;
  }
  @foreach (var field in Model.ConsentQuestions)
    {
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-8">
          @Html.Label(string.Format("ConsentQuestions[{0}].Key", i), field.Key)
          @Html.Hidden(string.Format("ConsentQuestions[{0}].Key", i), field.Key)
        </div>
        <p class="col-md-2">
          @Html.RadioButton(string.Format("ConsentQuestions[{0}].Value", i), true, htmlAttributes: new { id = string.Format("question{0}-true", i) })
          <label for="question@(i)-true">Yes</label>
          @Html.RadioButton(string.Format("ConsentQuestions[{0}].Value", i), false, htmlAttributes: new { id = string.Format("question{0}-false", i) })
          <label for="question@(i)-false">No</label>
        </p>
      </div>
      i++;
    }
```

`Model.ConsentQuestions` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>` (the reason for this is that the questions are user-definable).  For whatever reason, the binder can't figure out this one out.  Usually this sort of indexing works fine with collections (I am doing something similar with other IEnumerables with no issue).  What's strange is if I breakpoint my validating method, it sees that there are the right number of items in ConsentQuestions, except each KVP is {"", false}.

I'd like to know how to correct the problem and get the values in the form to bind.

**edit:**  I do have a seemingly working solution in using a class that inherits from `DefaultModelBinder` and then overrides `GetPropertyValue` to look right at `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form`... while that's fine as far as it goes I'd still like to know why in this case it isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried passing a List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>>` instead and indexing with your `i` index, using `RadioButtonFor(m=>ConsentQuestions[i].Value)` syntax? That usually gets the indexed element binding right.

Comment: Oh, one addendum:  that should be m => m.ConsentQuestions[i].Value in your example.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment (except for a typo), you need to use a List, not an IEnumerable (as that cannot be indexed at runtime by the binder) and use the `For` helpers on the index properties.

### My TestModel looks like:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>> ConsentQuestions { get; set; }
    public TestModel()
    {
        var consentQuestions = new List<KeyValuePair<string,bool>>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            consentQuestions.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,bool>("Question " + i.ToString(), i % 2 == 0));
        }
        this.ConsentQuestions = consentQuestions;
    }
}
```

I then applied `...For` version of the helpers on the indexed element properties:

### View:

```
<div class="control-label col-md-8">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ConsentQuestions[i].Key)
</div>
<p class="col-md-2">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.ConsentQuestions[i].Value, true, htmlAttributes: new { id = string.Format("question{0}-true", i) })
    <label for="question@(i)-true">Yes</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ConsentQuestions[i].Value, false, htmlAttributes: new { id = string.Format("question{0}-false", i) })
    <label for="question@(i)-false">No</label>
</p>
```

Note: I changed the `HiddenFor` to a `DisplayFor` to see the question (feel free to tweak).

### Which works:

[image]

### Followup:

I have been examining the output generated and the *only* difference is that using the first style of binding fails to match the existing value (the second one works). This applies to using a solid class or the KeyValuePair (makes no difference). It looks like the `RadioButton` binder is broken, but the `RadionButtonFor` is not:

```
@Html.RadioButton("ConsentQuestions[" + i.ToString() + "].Value", true, htmlAttributes: new { id = string.Format("question{0}-true", i) })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ConsentQuestions[i].Value, false, htmlAttributes: new { id = string.Format("question{0}-false", i) })
```

### Results in half working!:

[image]

This is obviously a little bizarre, as it should work the same, but the solution is still to just use the `For` versions of the helpers. **Strongly typed code is always preferable to strings anyway.**

Comment: In your testing was there any difference with the keys?  In my case neither was binding.

Comment: @emodendroket: sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you please clarify?

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ConsentQuestions[i].Key)`... in my case, this was also failing to bind and so if the page failed the validation it would reload with all the labels blank.  Did you have any issues with this?

Comment: @emodendroket: Can you please post your controller `Edit` actions etc so i can update my test project and see if there is another issue at work?

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your model to use a `Dictionary` (which is literally a list of `KeyValuePairs`). You won't even need to change your view.

So something like this:

```
public ActionResult AnswerQuestions(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> ConsentQuestions)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Would be changed to this:

```
public ActionResult AnswerQuestions(Dictionary<string, bool> ConsentQuestions)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

The main difference is that in addition to the properties that `IEnumerable` has, it also has `.Comparer`, `.ContainsKey()`, `.ContainsValue()`, `.Count`, `.Keys`, `.TryGetValue()`, and `.Values`.

Here's a full answer on [why binding `KeyValuePairs` doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300811/1507941).

Comment: Strictly speaking, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` (which means the current specification can accept dictionaries).  Interesting point about the structs; I hadn't thought about that.